# CGLayer in UIScrollView crashes

Tags: ios, performance, scroll, draw, layer

I have a class that inherits from UIScrollView. The drawRect function uses a CGLayer to cache the drawing to allow for faster scrolling. Unfortunately the code is crashing every time I try to scroll the view.

As soon as a click and drag in the iOS simulator it crashes with errors such as the following:

> 2012-08-04 19:11:09.687 scrolllayertest[3197:c07] -[__NSCFType
>   animationKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x682aa20
>   2012-08-04 19:11:09.689 scrolllayertest[3197:c07] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFType animationKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x682aa20'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x14b2022 0xeb2cd6 0x14b3cbd 0x1418ed0 0x1418cb2 0x4ca94 0x492a5 0x49459 0x5e157 0x49765 0x1449f1a 0x1415635
>   0x1415026 0x4966b 0x49765 0x1449f1a 0x1415635 0x1415026 0x4966b
>   0x43dbd 0x15ca0 0x139cef5 0x1486195 0x13eaff2 0x13e98da 0x13e8d84
>   0x13e8c9b 0x139b7d8 0x139b88a 0x15626 0x21ed 0x2155 0x1) terminate
>   called throwing an exception

I can't work out what the problem is. I will paste the code in below. Also this is in iOS 5.1 on the iPad Simulator. I haven't testing it yet on the device.

LayerTest.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LayerTest : UIScrollView

@end
```

LayerTest.m

```
#import "LayerTest.h"

@interface LayerTest ()
@property (nonatomic,assign) CGLayerRef layer;
@end

@implementation LayerTest
@synthesize layer;

- (void)setLayer:(CGLayerRef)aLayer {
    if (layer)
        CGLayerRelease(layer);
    layer = aLayer;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.layer = nil;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    CGSize sz = self.bounds.size;
    sz.width *= 2;
    self.contentSize = sz;
    self.layer = nil;
}

- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    [super setContentOffset:contentOffset];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (self.layer == nil) {
        self.layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, self.contentSize, NULL);
        CGContextRef contextLayer = CGLayerGetContext(self.layer);
        CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentSize.width, self.contentSize.height);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextLayer, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
        CGContextFillRect(contextLayer, contentRect);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextLayer, [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextLayer, contentRect);
    }
    if (self.layer)
        CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context, CGPointZero, self.layer);
}

@end
```

Any suggestions for how to fix?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could narrow it down to which line causes it, since I don't see a call to the function mentioned in the error message anywhere in your code.

Comment: The line causing the crash seems to be the call to CGLayerCreateWithContext. That is, if I comment out the call to this function there is no crash. The actual crash occurs somewhere in the main loop however, not from my code.